# Google font not working with bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-font-api

I'm trying to use Google Font on a page. In my html I used:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And in my CSS:

```
@import url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans');
```

Still whenI use "Open Sans" with the font-family attribute it stays on Arial.

```
body
{
    background-color: #F1F1F2;
    font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a live example or a fiddle ? I'm pretty sure bootstrap has some font property on all text element such as p, span etc. This is overriding your body font-family value.

Comment: @franchez I guess it would make sense, however I applied user3217672 method and it seemed to work with no !important tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using google font on any webpage is very easy and you can load the fonts asynchronously.

If you don't use the direct code that Google font delivers and you simply load the following url:

> http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600

You'd be represented the source code (CSS).

Now, copy and paste the displayed code in the CSS source of your website.

You can then use your selected google font(s) on your webpages using the following:

```
body
{
    background-color: #F1F1F2;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial;
}
```

That's enough and it will work.

Comment: Thanks, that seems cleaner that embedding indeed.

Answer (score 3):

I have a hunch that your bootstrap is being loaded after the CSS for your Google font.  Find the point that you are importing this CSS:

`@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";`

Then add your Google code AFTER that to make sure that it is not being overwritten by the bootstrap.

Good Luck!

Comment: I was running into the exact same problem, but was not finding out where the solution was. Here this was the problem all along. Thank you so much for pointing this out, I don't think I would have figured this part out.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you dont need to do it twice! any one kind of **FONT ASSOCIATION** is enough !!

Warning that overuse of `@import` may cause a overhead!

Bootstrap(if you have used it) usually overrides the font with -> `font-family:"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif`

Working Demo -> [Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/ujc7m/)

**Note** : I have added the font as external resources. It seems to be working properly !

Answer (score 0):

just do `!important` after the font style you want to use

Comment: Can you include a working example of using `!important` with styles to your answer