# Bootstrap overriding Google Font

Tags: html, fonts

Despite looking at other answers I cannot get Bootstrap to not override the Google Font I want to use.  I have tried changing the position of my stylesheets but nothing works.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

http://codepen.io/01scatman/pen/KzGdNY

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AOS-TC.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: Where do you specify your "arvo" font in your CSS. Use the `@font-face` CSS rule to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. To solve it, first, in your header **put your static CSS link lower than all other ones**, i.e. you need something like this

From

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AOS-TC.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

To

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AOS-TC.css">
```

Second, **add the proper font in your CSS 'body' tag**

From

```
font-family: Arvo;
```

To

```
font-family: 'Arvo', sans-serif;
```

Maybe this is a little bit late. However, I believe it will be helpful for people who might have the same problem in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I have nothing but the following in a document, and it works.  Bootstrap is not overwriting the font.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="AOS-TC.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arvo' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<style>
  body{
    font-family: 'Arvo', serif;
  }
</style>

Hello
```

Comment: I tried both of these and neither worked.  I'm at a loss.

Comment: check this out:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21678458/google-font-not-working-with-bootstrap

Comment: I've looked at this prior and it did not help.

Comment: I'll play around with it

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding "important" on your body CSS

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: .1px;
  position: relative;
  background: url(http://www.adventuresofscatman.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/IMG_4273.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Arvo !important;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

Comment: or you can download the CSS and host it into your server

https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css

and replace the font-family on the specific tag where you want the Arvo font to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the font is being overridden, but you can use [fontSwitcher](http://codepen.io/freginold/pen/vLJewY) (on CodePen) to apply it.  I tried it on your pen and it applies Arvo.  Add this line to the head:

`<script src="http://codepen.io/freginold/pen/vLJewY.js"></script>`

And this line to the JavaScript section:

`fontSwitcher('fontName', 'elementClass');`

fontSwitcher applies the Google font by class, so if you want to apply it to the whole body, assign a class to the body and then apply the font to that class.

You can also specify fallback fonts, like this:

`fontSwitcher('fontName', 'elementClass'[, 'fallbackFont1', 'fallbackFont2' ...]);`

Disclaimer: fontSwitcher is still a work in progress, but it's fully functional.

Comment: Also, adding `font-family: Arvo;` to the `.secondary` class applies Arvo to your sub-heading, so maybe you just need to target the font differently.